# About the algorithm of reading sensor data in compass driver mmc3x30.c?

Tags: android, linux, driver, android-sensors, compass

- I am working to bring up the mmc3630kj at msm8909. The driver code is in drivers/input/misc/mmc3x30.c. But I do not understand about the reading data function "mmc3x30_read_xyz". What the algorithm of calculating the tmp.x tmp.y and tmp.z? I have no idea about it? Could anyone can give me some notes?
  Here is the code:

  ```
  /* read xyz raw data */
  rc = regmap_bulk_read(memsic->regmap, MMC3X30_REG_DATA, data, 6);

  if (rc) {
      dev_err(&memsic->i2c->dev, "read reg %d failed at %d.(%d)\n",
                                     MMC3X30_REG_DATA, __LINE__, rc);
      goto exit;
  }


  tmp.x = (((u8)data[1]) << 8 | (u8)data[0]) - 32768;
  tmp.y = (((u8)data[3]) << 8 | (u8)data[2]) - (((u8)data[5]) << 8 | (u8)data[4]) ;
  tmp.z = (((u8)data[3]) << 8 | (u8)data[2]) +  (((u8)data[5]) << 8 | (u8)data[4]) - 32768 - 32768;

  vec->x = tmp.x;
  vec->y = tmp.y;
  vec->z = -tmp.z;
  ```